# Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list' error

Tags: java, android

When I'm trying to run my program I have the next error. I watched other similar questions and the guys asked if they have a List View's in their code. The problem is that I haven't got List View's or List Activities in my code.

Here is my project on [GitHub](https://github.com/bottleIsEmpty/networkControl).

Here is the error log:

```
08-08 19:41:53.948 2473-2473/su.rck.networkcontrol E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: su.rck.networkcontrol, PID: 2473
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{su.rck.networkcontrol/su.rck.networkcontrol.BidListActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:346)
at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:147)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1343)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1574)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1641)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:794)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2200)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2153)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2063)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:554)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1188)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Comment: Please don't just link to your project off-site. You need to include a [mcve] in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Change your `BidListFragment extends ListFragment` to `BidListFragment extends Fragment` it will work fine. And you are not using Any property of ListFragment, So you can use Fragment itself

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html)

> To do this, your view hierarchy must contain a ListView object with
>   the id "@android:id/list" (or list if it's in code)